# how to add commands in .ssh/authorized_keys

Tags: sshd

I read on `man sshd` one can add post-login processing when a user logs in using a particular key:

```
environment="FOO=BAR" ssh-rsa AAA... keytag
```

But when I try to ssh into the system, the target host does not register the line and instead asks for a password. What is the right way of adding this? I would like to do something like

```
command="echo|mail -s ${USER},${HOSTNAME} a.monitored.email@example.com" ssh-rsa AAA... keytag
```

I am using Suse SLE 11 SP2.

Thanks
Dinesh

Comment: Trying now with AuthorizedKeysCommand yes and AuthorizedKeysCommandRunAs nobody

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, according to the [documentation](http://www.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi/OpenBSD-current/man8/sshd.8?query=sshd&sec=8) `command = "command"`:

> Specifies that the command is executed whenever this key is used for authentication.  ***The command supplied by the user (if any) is ignored.***  The command is run on a pty if the client requests a pty; otherwise it is run without a tty.  If an 8-bit clean channel is required, one must not request a pty or should specify **no-pty**.  A quote may be included in the command by quoting it with a backslash.  This option might be useful to restrict certain public keys to perform just a specific operation.  An example might be a key that permits remote backups but nothing else.  Note that the client may specify TCP and/or X11 forwarding unless they are explicitly prohibited.  The command originally supplied by the client is available in the `SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND` environment variable.  Note that this option applies to shell, command or subsystem execution.  Also note that this command may be superseded by either a [sshd_config(5)](http://www.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi/OpenBSD-current/man5/ssh_config.5?query=ssh_config&sec=5) **ForceCommand** directive or a command embedded in a certificate.

Using this option, it is possible to enforce execution of a given command when this key is used for authentication *and no other.* This is not what you're looking for.

To run a command after login, you can add in the file `~/bashrc` something like this:

```bash
if [[ -n $SSH_CONNECTION ]] ; then
    echo|mail -s ${USER},${HOSTNAME} a.monitored.email@example.com"
fi
```

Second, you need to verify the permissions of the `authorized_keys` file and the folder / parent folders in which it is located.

```
chmod 700 ~/.ssh
chmod 600 ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

For more information see: https://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/doc/openssh-server/faq.html#3.14

Comment: I am looking to execute a command only when SSH connection is successfully authenticated and not from later sub shells which too get the SSH_* variables. File perms look ok. But thanks for the links.

Comment: @Dinesh maybe this will work http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/networking_2ndEd/ssh/ch08_04.htm

Comment: Thanks  And also that my approach wouldn't have worked - it executed the command and exited, defeating my purpose very soundly!! Thanks again

Comment: The link to the FAQ at openssh.org is now a 404.  They seem to have removed the whole FAQ from the website.